# can a condition be in range in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

can a range have a condition in python? for example, I wanna start at position 0 but I want it to run until my while statement is fulfilled.

```
total = 0
num = int(input ( "Enter a number: " ))
range[0,while num != 0:]
total += num
```

I want to be able to save different variables being in a while loop.
The purpose of my program is to print the sum of the numbers you enter unil you put in 0

**my code**

```
num = int(input ( "Enter a number: " )) #user input
number_enterd = str() #holds numbers enterd
total = 0 #sum of number

while num != 0:
    total += num

    num = int(input ( "Enter a number: " ))

    number_enterd = num


print( "Total is =", total ) 
print(number_enterd) #check to see the numbers ive collected
```

---

expected output:
enter an integer number (0 to end): 10
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55

---

as of right now I'm trying to figure out how to store different variables so i can print them before the total is displayed. but since it is in a loop, the variable just keeps getting overwritten until the end.

Comment: Sounds like you want `number_enterd` to be a `list` to which you `append` on each loop?

Comment: Do you know about [data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I used a boolean to exit out of the loop

```
def add_now():
    a = 0
    exit_now = False
    while exit_now is False:
        user_input = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        print("{} + {} =  {} ".format(user_input, a, user_input + a))
        a += user_input
        if user_input == 0:
            exit_now = True
    print(a)


add_now()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store all the numbers you get as input, the simplest way to do that in Python is to just use a list. Here's that concept given your code, with slight modification:

```
num = int(input ( "Enter a number: " )) #user input
numbers_entered = [] #holds numbers entered
total = 0 #sum of number

while num != 0:
    total += num
    numbers_entered.append(num)
    num = int(input ( "Enter a number: " ))


print("Total is = " + str(total)) 
print(numbers_entered) #check to see the numbers ive collected
```

To get any desired formatting of those numbers, just modify that last print statement with a string concatenation similar to the one on the line above it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store all of the values entered and then print them, you may use a list. You code would end like this:

```
#number_enterd = str() # This is totally unnecessary. This does nothing

num = int(input ( "Enter a number: " ))
total = 0 #sum of number
numsEntered = [] # An empty list to hold the values we will enter
numsEntered.append(num) # Add the first number entered to the list
while num != 0:
    total += num
    num = int(input ( "Enter a number: " ))

    #number_enterd = num # Unnecesary as well, this overwrites what you wrote in line 2
                         # It doesn't even make the num a string

    numsEntered.append(num) #This adds the new num the user just entered into the list


print("Total is =", total )
print("Numbers entered:", numsEntered) #check to see the numbers you've collected
```

For example, user enters 5,2,1,4,5,7,8,0 as inputs from the num input request.
Your output will be:

```
>>>Total is = 32
>>>Numbers entered: [5, 2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 0]
```

Just as a guide, this is how I would do it. Hope it helps:

```
num = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
numsEntered = [] # An empty list to hold the values we will enter
total = 0 #sum of numbers
while True:
    numsEntered.append(num) #This adds the num the user just entered into the list
    total += num
    num = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))

print("Total is =", total)
print("Numbers entered:", numsEntered) #check to see the numbers you've collected
```

In this case, the last 0 entered to get out of the loop doesn't show up. At least, I wouldn't want it to show up since it doesn't add anything to the sum.
Hope you like my answer! Have a good day :)